# How to do this in one SQL or Django ORM command?

Tags: sql, django, django-models, orm, django-filter

I'm trying to write a query which depends on two `ForeignKeys`.

There is an **Product** which can have many **Occurence** objects (ForeignKey). **Occurence** object can have many **Scan** objects (ForeignKey too).

Now I want to get for every occurence of object last scan, if its attribute **price** is not Null (Price is a OneToOneField), according to its **datetime** attribute.

The naive approach:

```
product = Product.objects.first()
scans = []
for occ in product.occurences.all():
    scan = occ.scans.filter(price__isnull=False).orderby("-datetime").first()
    if scan:
        scans.append(scan)

>>> result is scans list
```

This approach has many disadvantages. One product can have hundreds of occurences and millions of scans so the best would be database to do the work.

So I'm looking for query which can do this.

```
Scan.objects.filter(occurence__product=product,price__isnull=False)
```

this returns all scans for the product with not null price attribute. I think I should use `GroupBy` but I don't know how.

Comment: Why would you need a `GROUP BY`? You don't have any annotations, and you're selecting all the columns from `Scan`, so I don't see how it would have any effect. When you do need a `GROUP BY`, Django automatically adds it to the query.

Comment: I thought that I should group Scans by their Occurence and then, from each group, get the latest Scan. Maybe I don't need GROUP BY. Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is your Model architecture..

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # fields

class Occurence(models.Model):
    # some other fields
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)


class Scan(models.Model):
    # a few other fields
    occurence = models.ForeignKey(Occurence)
```

If this is case, you should be able to do this

```
product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
occurences = product.occurence_set.all()
scans = Occurence.scan_set.filter(occurence__in = occurences).order_by('-date_field')[:n]
```

It is not clear in which model you are checking if the price is null. You can add price filter to that model, either for occurances or scans...

order_by sorts data by the field. In django, slicing([:n] is like `limit` in MySQL or `top` in SQL).

**Get the latest element of each occurance**

This would work only if data is not inserted by bulk_create/data is insterted into the table at the same time.

```
Occurence.scan_set.filter(occurence__in = occurences).annotate(latest_scan=Max('occurance__scan__date_field')).filter(date_field=F('latest_scan'))
```

Ideally it should be time field, as you said that it would have quite a few scan instances.

Comment: Yes, the model architecture is good. There are two problems in your answer, the first is that scans number can be very high (millions) so I can't select them all from the database. Another thing is that I want only last scans (lowest datetime).

Comment: I have added order_by and slicing to select the latest scans from the query. Please let me know if anything else need to be added.

Comment: The first problem is that all scans are loaded into the memory (which I can't do) and the second problem is that it doesn't returns correct result (it can return n latest scans from one occurence.

Comment: 1. it doesn't load all the scans to the memory. django converts this query into a sql query and converts this slicing into `LIMIT` of sql. just do `print(Occurence.scan_set.filter(occurence__in = occurences).order_by('-date_field')[:n].query)` you will get the sql query that's generated. 

2. It wouldn't output scans from only one occurance as we are doing order_by after filtering the occurances. 

I think this is one of the right ways. As everything is happening in the SQL

Comment: Ok, but still theres a problem that it can return occurence1.somescan occurence1.somescan etc. I want occurence1.lastscan occurence2.lastscan ... occurence_n.lastscan

Comment: do you just want only the lastest 1 scan or n scans? if it's only 1 scan, I would recommend to store it in Occurance model itself. Let me know if you want it for n scans

Comment: I want to avoid saving it in Occurence model, it's not safe I think. Yes I want 1 scan from every Occurence (see the question)

Comment: I don't think if that would be unsafe. The reason is, if someone is able to access your database, then it doesn't matter whether it is in a different model/table right?